# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object error in laravel

Tags: laravel, request

here is my function.

```
public function get(Request $request){
       
        $bike1 = $request->input('bike1');
        $bike2 = $request->input('bike2');
        //dd($bike1);
        return $bike2->name;
    }
```

When i use the dd function, the result is:

```
"{"id":1,"created_at":"2020-09-16T12:33:25.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-09-16T12:33:25.000000Z","name":"302r","brand":"benelli","price":800000,"displacement":300,"segment":"300cc","power":"28KW@10000 rpm","torque":"27Nm@9000rpm","fuel_delivery_system":"Efi","abs":"1","cooling_system":"Liquid","weight":155} ◀"
```

But when I try to access the name property(any) i get the error.

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

What I might be missing?

Comment: try `return $bike2['name'];` instead of ``return $bike2->name;

Comment: you can't use `$bike2->name;` as `$bike2` it is not any class instance. use `$bike2['name'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $bike1 is a JSON string, before you can access it's attributes you need to decode it.

```
$bike1 = json_decode($request->input('bike1'));
return $bike1->name
```

If that doesn't work $bike1 may be an array, not an object, in that case, this should work

```
return $bike1['name']
```

Comment: yeah it worked with the first method. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you missed that you returned a string, not an object

Comment: how can i return it in an object ?

Answer (score 0):

**first decode your json then after get you name**

```
$bike2 = json_decode($request->input('bike2'));
return $bike2->name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode `$bike2` because it's in JSON format, so you can do

```
$decoded_bike2 = json_decode($request->input('bike2'));
```

This will return an object

```
{#1236 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"created_at": "2020-09-16T12:33:25.000000Z"
  +"updated_at": "2020-09-16T12:33:25.000000Z"
  +"name": "302r"
}
```

you can access name property like

```
return $decoded_bike2->name;
```

If you do

```
$decoded_bike2 = json_decode($request->input('bike2'), true);
```

This will return an array

```
array:4 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "created_at" => "2020-09-16T12:33:25.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2020-09-16T12:33:25.000000Z"
  "name" => "302r"
]
```

You can access key name like

```
return $decoded_bike2['name'];
```

For more details about `json_decode()` [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)